# how to get my python tally app to subtract?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I created a tkinter python tally app and i just want to be able to plus 1 or minus 1 from the click of a button. Just a regular tally app. The problem im having is that the plus 1 always works but when i want to minus 1 it automatically turns to a negative number. here is my script:

```
total_count = 0

def count_number():
    global total_count
    total_count = total_count + 1
    count_label["text"] = total_count


minus_count = total_count

def minus_number():
    global minus_count
    minus_count = minus_count - 1
    count_label["text"] = minus_count


count_label = Label(root, fg="orange", font="Verdana 150 bold italic")
count_label.pack()
count_label.place(x=810, y=280)



plus_button = Button(root, text="+ 1", width=10, fg="purple", command=count_number).place(x=910, y=870)
minus_button = Button(root, text="- 1", width=10, fg="purple", command=minus_number).place(x=910, y=970)
```

How can i both add and subtract 1 from the same number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the line `minus_count = total_count` `minus_count` is assigned the **value** of `total_count` which is 0. So these events occur in order:

1. `total_count = 0`
2. `minus_count = 0`
3. plus is executed, which increases `total_count`, not `minus_count`
4. minus is executed which subtracts 1 from `minus_count`, resulting in `-1`

Easy fix will be to use the same variable in both places:

```
total_count = 0

def count_number():
    global total_count
    total_count = total_count + 1
    count_label["text"] = total_count


def minus_number():
    global total_count
    total_count= total_count- 1
    count_label["text"] = total_count


count_label = Label(root, fg="orange", font="Verdana 150 bold italic")
count_label.pack()
count_label.place(x=810, y=280)



plus_button = Button(root, text="+ 1", width=10, fg="purple", command=count_number).place(x=910, y=870)
minus_button = Button(root, text="- 1", width=10, fg="purple", command=minus_number).place(x=910, y=970)
```

Comment: oh i see where i went wrong,. yes this worked perfect, thanks so much!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. This way you mark for future readers that your question is resolved and what helpted you